# Error while installing Box2D Python package for use with OpenAI Gym

Tags: pip, openai-gym

I am trying to install OpenAI's Gym in Windows 10, according to this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-install-openai-gym-in-a-windows-environment-338969e24d30).

I followed most of the steps without problems. However, at the step for installing `Box2D` with `pip`, I get the errors below. `MyEnv` is my current conda environment. How can I address this problem?

```
(MyEnv) C:\Users\me>pip install Box2D
Collecting Box2D
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/7b/ddb96fea1fa5b24f8929714ef483f64c33e9649e7aae066e5f5023ea426a/Box2D-2.3.2.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: Box2D
  Building wheel for Box2D (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\COBRA\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v1w5reok\\Box2D\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v1w5reok\\Box2D\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-58bpeewu' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-v1w5reok\Box2D\
  Complete output (338 lines):
  Using setuptools (version 41.2.0).
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D
  copying library\Box2D\Box2D.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D
  copying library\Box2D\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D\b2
  copying library\Box2D\b2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D\b2
  running build_ext
  building 'Box2D._Box2D' extension
  swigging Box2D\Box2D.i to Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp
  C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\COBRA\Library\bin\swig.exe -python -c++ -IBox2D -small -O -includeall -ignoremissing -w201 -globals b2Globals -outdir library\Box2D -keyword -w511 -D_SWIG_KWARGS -o Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp Box2D\Box2D.i
  Box2D\Common\b2Math.h(67) : Warning 302: Identifier 'b2Vec2' redefined by %extend (ignored),
  Box2D\Box2D_math.i(47) : Warning 302: %extend definition of 'b2Vec2'.
  Box2D\Common\b2Math.h(158) : Warning 302: Identifier 'b2Vec3' redefined by %extend (ignored),
  Box2D\Box2D_math.i(168) : Warning 302: %extend definition of 'b2Vec3'.
  Box2D\Common\b2Math.h(197) : Warning 302: Identifier 'b2Mat22' redefined by %extend (ignored),
  Box2D\Box2D_math.i(301) : Warning 302: %extend definition of 'b2Mat22'.
  Box2D\Common\b2Math.h(271) : Warning 302: Identifier 'b2Mat33' redefined by %extend (ignored),
  Box2D\Box2D_math.i(372) : Warning 302: %extend definition of 'b2Mat33'.
  Box2D\Collision\b2DynamicTree.h(44) : Warning 312: Nested union not currently supported (ignored).
  Box2D\Common\b2Settings.h(144) : Warning 506: Can't wrap varargs with keyword arguments enabled
  Box2D\Common\b2Math.h(91) : Warning 509: Overloaded method b2Vec2::operator ()(int32) effectively ignored,
  Box2D\Common\b2Math.h(85) : Warning 509: as it is shadowed by b2Vec2::operator ()(int32) const.
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\box2d
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\box2d\dynamics
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\box2d\dynamics\contacts
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\box2d\dynamics\joints
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\box2d\common
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\box2d\collision
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\box2d\collision\shapes
  C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\COBRA\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64 -IC:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\COBRA\include -IC:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\COBRA\include -c Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\box2d\box2d_wrap.o -I.
  Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp: In function 'bool b2CheckVertices(b2Vec2*, int32, bool)':
  Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp:3760:16: warning: variable 'm_centroid' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
           b2Vec2 m_centroid = __b2ComputeCentroid(vertices, count);
                  ^
  Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp: In function 'long int b2ContactPoint___hash__(b2ContactPoint*)':
  Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp:4181:77: error: cast from 'b2ContactPoint*' to 'long int' loses precision [-fpermissive]
   SWIGINTERN long b2ContactPoint___hash__(b2ContactPoint *self){ return (long)self; }
                                                                               ^
  Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp: In function 'long int b2AssertException___hash__(b2AssertException*)':
  Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp:4205:83: error: cast from 'b2AssertException*' to 'long int' loses precision [-fpermissive]
   SWIGINTERN long b2AssertException___hash__(b2AssertException *self){ return (long)self; }

<lots of errors from Box2D_wrap.cpp>
                                                                           ^
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\COBRA\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Box2D
  Running setup.py clean for Box2D
Failed to build Box2D
Installing collected packages: Box2D
  Running setup.py install for Box2D ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\COBRA\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v1w5reok\\Box2D\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v1w5reok\\Box2D\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7ni40amu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-v1w5reok\Box2D\
    Complete output (338 lines):
    Using setuptools (version 41.2.0).
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D
    copying library\Box2D\Box2D.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D
    copying library\Box2D\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D\b2
    copying library\Box2D\b2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Box2D\b2
    running build_ext
    building 'Box2D._Box2D' extension
    swigging Box2D\Box2D.i to Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp
    C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\COBRA\Library\bin\swig.exe -python -c++ -IBox2D -small -O -includeall -ignoremissing -w201 -globals b2Globals -outdir library\Box2D -keyword -w511 -D_SWIG_KWARGS -o Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp Box2D\Box2D.i
    Box2D\Common\b2Math.h(67) : Warning 302: Identifier 'b2Vec2' redefined by %extend (ignored),
    Box2D\Box2D_math.i(47) : Warning 302: %extend definition of 'b2Vec2'.
    Box2D\Common\b2Math.h(158) : Warning 302: Identifier 'b2Vec3' redefined by %extend (ignored),
    Box2D\Box2D_math.i(168) : Warning 302: %extend definition of 'b2Vec3'.
    Box2D\Common\b2Math.h(197) : Warning 302: Identifier 'b2Mat22' redefined by %extend (ignored),
    Box2D\Box2D_math.i(301) : Warning 302: %extend definition of 'b2Mat22'.
    Box2D\Common\b2Math.h(271) : Warning 302: Identifier 'b2Mat33' redefined by %extend (ignored),
    Box2D\Box2D_math.i(372) : Warning 302: %extend definition of 'b2Mat33'.
    Box2D\Collision\b2DynamicTree.h(44) : Warning 312: Nested union not currently supported (ignored).
    Box2D\Common\b2Settings.h(144) : Warning 506: Can't wrap varargs with keyword arguments enabled
    Box2D\Common\b2Math.h(91) : Warning 509: Overloaded method b2Vec2::operator ()(int32) effectively ignored,
    Box2D\Common\b2Math.h(85) : Warning 509: as it is shadowed by b2Vec2::operator ()(int32) const.
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\box2d
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\box2d\dynamics
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\box2d\dynamics\contacts
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\box2d\dynamics\joints
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\box2d\common
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\box2d\collision
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\box2d\collision\shapes
    C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\COBRA\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64 -IC:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\COBRA\include -IC:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\COBRA\include -c Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\box2d\box2d_wrap.o -I.
    Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp: In function 'bool b2CheckVertices(b2Vec2*, int32, bool)':
    Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp:3760:16: warning: variable 'm_centroid' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
             b2Vec2 m_centroid = __b2ComputeCentroid(vertices, count);
                    ^
<lots of errors from Box2D_wrap.cpp>
                                                                           ^
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\COBRA\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\COBRA\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v1w5reok\\Box2D\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v1w5reok\\Box2D\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7ni40amu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

(MyEnv) C:\Users\me>
```

Comment: It seems you are using `mingw-64 gcc` compiler to build on windows. You should use Visual Studio C++ Build Tools (with Windows 10 SDK). You should also show the actual error output instead of warnings so we can tell what went wrong. The build failed because of the errors.